# Android 6.0 incorrectly handles drawCircle method

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow

In my app I need to draw circles using bitmap and the drawCircle() method.

Everything was working fine and exactly as it should up until Android 6.0.

It still draws circles on all the previous versions, but draws rectangles when I use the app on 6.0. But **if I change it to be filled, it draws a circle both in api 22 and api 23.**
Anyone has the same problem or any idea why this happens?

Here is the source code and a screenshot (app running on API 23 on the left, and API 22 on the right). [same app on different api's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kbTDd.png)

```
 public final class Circle1View extends View {

    private float xCenter, yCenter;
    private Bitmap grid = null;

    public Circle1View (Context context) {
        super(context);
        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        setLayerType(View.LAYER_TYPE_SOFTWARE, null);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        int w = getWidth();
        int h = getHeight();
        xCenter = w / 2;
        yCenter = h / 2;

        drawBitmaps(w, h);

        canvas.translate(xCenter, yCenter);
        canvas.scale(xCenter, yCenter);

        canvas.drawBitmap(grid, null, new RectF(-1, -1, 1, 1), null);
    }


    private void drawBitmaps(int w, int h) {

        grid  = Bitmap.createBitmap(w, h, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
        Canvas canvas = new Canvas();

        canvas.translate(xCenter, yCenter);
        canvas.scale(xCenter, yCenter);

        Paint gridPaint = new Paint();

        gridPaint.setStrokeWidth(0.01f);
        // Works with FILL
        // gridPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);
        gridPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

        canvas.setBitmap(grid);

        canvas.drawCircle(0, 0, 0.5f, gridPaint);


    }
}
```

Comment: I would try to refactor the way you are drawing the circles. Could you describe what have to be drawn? For example: a circle centered with radius equals to half width.

Answer (score 1):

I think it has something to do with the scaling and translation you do. Imagine the circle that is drawn is so small, it only takes 4 pixels. When enlarging this back to the full size, you are left with 4 straight lines between these pixels.

When I change the stroke width to 0.04f, the issue is gone. I would suggest you simplify your code by drawing on the supplied `Canvas` directly:

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    int w = getWidth();
    int h = getHeight();
    xCenter = w / 2;
    yCenter = h / 2;

    Paint gridPaint = new Paint();

    gridPaint.setStrokeWidth(1f);
    gridPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    canvas.drawCircle(xCenter, yCenter, w/4, gridPaint);
}
```

As for your question about the difference between API levels: Marshmallow introduced changes for `drawBitmap()`. You can have a look at the respective source code for [Lollipop](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/lollipop-mr1-release/libs/hwui/OpenGLRenderer.cpp#L2150) and [Marshmallow](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/marshmallow-release/libs/hwui/OpenGLRenderer.cpp#L1664).

Comment: This was my first thought. But it is working on api < 23. How could us explain that?

Comment: I had a look at the Android source code. There are some major changes to the code for `drawBitmap`. I didn't look into the details, but I wouldn't be surprised if that is the reason. I will add the links to my answer.

Comment: Nice. I agree that drawing to the canvas directly would be the best option.

Comment: I've just tried to pass a Canvas from onDraw and the problem still exists. Something is wrong with canvas.scale method - try to substitute stroke width to 0.04f and you will notice that circle became strangely rectangled.

Comment: It looks it's known issue: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&q=190523&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&id=190523